# XML Transformation for dynamic elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Assume the following xml input.

```
<Report Name="Report2" >
 <ITable i_id="Item ID" i_name="Item Name" heart_beat="Heart Beat" is_active="Is Active">
      <FkItemID_Collection>
           <FkItemID i_id="1">
                <i_name i_name="80">
                     <heart_beat heart_beat="0">
                          <is_active is_active="True">
                               <Tags>
                                    <Tag Name="ItemClass" Value="Division"/>
                                    <Tag Name="ItemDisplayName" Value="80"/>
                                    <Tag Name="ItemName" Value="80"/>
                                    <Tag Name="ItemType" Value="Logical"/> 
                               </Tags>
                          </is_active>
                     </heart_beat>
                </i_name>
           </FkItemID>
           <FkItemID i_id="2">
            //Same formatted day as above element
           </FkItemID>
      </FkItemID_Collection>
 </ITable>
</Report>
```

Specialty about the XML is that there can be many elements like  , 
ex :

```
<i_name i_name="80">
           <i_price i_price ="10">
                 <heart_beat heart_beat="0">`
```

likewise.

The number of such elements can be dynamically changed. The tags always come inside a `<Tags>` block.

As the end result I am expecting an output like this

```
<Report Name="Report2">
 <Table i_id="Item ID" i_name="item Name" heart_beat="heart_beat" col1="ItemClass" col2="ItemDisplayName" col3="ItemName" col4="ItemType" >
  <Details agent_id="1" agent_name="80" col1="Division" col2="80" col3="80" col4="Logical" />
  <Details i_id="2" i_name="BC" col1="Division" col2="BC" col3="BC" col4="Logical"   />
 </Table>
</Report>
```

I wrote a XSLT for the scenario. But Im having some issues with it which I was unable to solve. This is what I've developed up to now. I am stuck with the part where I dont know how depth I have to go inside elements until I find Tags block and How to cater Dynamically generated tags such as item_price which I mentioned above.

This is what I've done upto now.

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*[local-name()='ITable']">
    <xsl:element name="Table">
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:attribute name="i_id">Item ID</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="i_name">Item Name</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="i_beat">heart_beat</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./*/*/*/*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{concat('col', position())}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@TagName"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <xsl:element name="Details">
                    <xsl:attribute name="i_id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@i_id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="i_name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@i_name"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:for-each select="./*/*/*">
                            <xsl:attribute name="{concat('col', position())}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@TagValue"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

What is the best solution for this issue.

Comment: Do not tag your post with both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. Say what version you are working with - that's the purpose of those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The tags always come inside a  block.   ...
>   I am stuck with the part
>   where I dont know how depth I have to go inside elements until I find
>   Tags block

This is what the descendant axis is for: `descendant::Tags` or `//Tags` will "find" the Tags block for you, no matter how deep it is.